# django admin panel displays Object

Tags: django, django-models

In django admin panel, instead of the field value, Tablename object is being showed. For Ex, I have a class Team with a field name, in the admin panel, instead of the name of the field, Team Object is displayed in the list.

Comment: I think you have forget to add the __unicode__ or __str__ function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to define "**unicode**()" method, adding it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `__unicode__()` method for the `Team` class:

```
class Team(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```